# Close windows application

Tags: c#, uninstallation

is it possible to close a running application with another application?

I have implemented `APP1.exe` and `APP1_UNIN.exe`, I would that `APP1_UNIN.exe` kill running `APP1.exe` and uninstall it.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To uninstall an application, you can start a new process and invoke `msiexec.exe`, and on the [command line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367988%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) you can specify what to uninstall:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi;
//take your choice of which you want to use:
psi = new ProcessStartInfo("msiexec.exe", string.Format("/x {0}", "path of my msi"));
psi = new ProcessStartInfo("msiexec.exe", string.Format("/x /n {{{0}}}", "my product code"));
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = psi;
p.Start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **System.Diagnostics.Process** class:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.closemainwindow(v=VS.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.closemainwindow%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)

There's also a **Kill** method.

Answer (score 1):

At least to kill the running process you can do like this:

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach (Process process in processes) {
  if (process.ProcessName == "APP1.exe") {
    try {
      process.Kill();
      break;
      } catch (Exception) { 
        //handle any exception here
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Regarding uninstalling it, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

For closing, you can do it by killing its process. `System.Diagnostics.Process`

```
Process []pArray = Process.GetProcesses();

foreach(Process prc in pArray) {
    string s = prc.ProcessName;
    if (s.CompareTo("APP1") ==0) {
        prc.Kill();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes using System.Diagnostics

You can get the process and Kill the Process.